# How to do transactional without lose encapsulation?

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions

I have a code that saves a bean, and updates another bean in a DB via Hibernate. It must be do in the same transaction, because if something wrong occurs (f.ex launches a Exception) rollback must be executed for the two operations.

```
public class BeanDao extends ManagedSession {

public Integer save(Bean bean) {
    Session session = null;
    try {
        session = createNewSessionAndTransaction();

        Integer idValoracio = (Integer) session.save(bean);  // SAVE
        doOtherAction(bean);                                 // UPDATE

        commitTransaction(session);

        return idBean;
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        log.error("get failed", re);
        if (session != null) {
            rollbackTransaction(session);
        }
        throw re;
    }
}

private void doOtherAction(Bean bean) {
    Integer idOtherBean = bean.getIdOtherBean();
    OtherBeanDao otherBeanDao = new OtherBeanDao();
    OtherBean otherBean = otherBeanDao.findById(idOtherBean);
    .
    . (doing operations)
    .
    otherBeanDao.attachDirty(otherBean)
}
}
```

The problem is:

In case that

```
session.save(bean)
```

launches an error, then I get AssertionFailure, because the function doOtherAction (that is used in other parts of the project) uses session after a Exception is thrown.

The first thing I thought were extract the code of the function doOtherAction, but then I have the same code duplicate, and not seems the best practice to do it.

What is the best way to refactor this?

Answer (score 0):

It's a common practice to manage transactions at one level above DAOs, in services or other business logic classes. That way you can, based on the business/service logic, in one case do two DAO operations in one transaction and, in another case, do them in separate transactions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a huge fan of Declarative Transaction Management. If you can spare the time to get it working (piece of cake with an [Application Server](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncij.html) such as GlassFish or JBoss, and easy with [Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/transaction.html#transaction-declarative)). If you annotate your business method with `@TransactionAttribute(REQUIRED)` (it can even be set to be done as default) and it calls the two DAO methods you will get exactly what you want: everything gets committed at once or rolled back over an Exception.
This solution is about as loosely coupled as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

The others are correct in that they take in to account what are common practice currently.

But that doesn't really help you with your current practice.

What you should do is create two new DAO methods. Such as CreateGlobalSession and CommitGlobalSession.

What these do is the same thing as your current create and commit routines.

The difference is that they set a "global" session variable (most likely best done with a ThreadLocal). Then you change the current routines so that they check if this global session already exists. If your create detects the global session, then simply return it. If your commit detects the global session, then it does nothing.

Now when you want to use it you do this:

```
try {
    dao.createGlobalSession();
    beanA.save();
    beanb.save();
    Dao.commitGlobalSession();
} finally {
    dao.rollbackGlobalSession();
}
```

Make sure you wrap the process in a try block so that you can reset your global session if there's an error.

While the other techniques are considered best practice and ideally you could one day evolve to something like that, this will get you over the hump with little more than 3 new methods and changing two existing methods. After that the rest of your code stays the same.

Comment: as a guy that had to give maintenance to a lot of code that makes use of Shared Session / Transaction (anti) patterns, I can say that it is not wise to go with it at development phase just to avoid some configuration work and refactoring. This solution tends to blow up maintenance costs. At one point or another someone will forget to commit a transaction, sessions will leak, you will have problems with scheduled jobs or clustering the Application, etc. Of a totally pragmatic point of view, I'm not talking about "ideal" approaches, just of "proven to be cheap on the long run ones".

Comment: Just to amend what I've said: Shared sessions / transactions are the kind of workaround that quickly gets copied and pasted everywhere and sooner or latter becomes some sort of standard for transaction managment in the project. Please don´t create a monster.

Comment: @Anthony, sure, but here's the thing. This case is only need for actual transactions, which are (apparently) so far rare for this case. So, the normal mechanism of the DAO is still in place (which, of course, can still leak). Then, if someone were to want to later add another multi-bean transaction, they will likely cut-and-paste this original code, preserving the pattern. Granted, as a side effect. But, also, he hasn't mentioned whether his code is on server, on a client or what. To do what you suggest he needs EJB or Spring or some other framework. That may not be practical for him.

Comment: I get that, still, in a pure Java SE context, I would still prefer to refactor the code, receive the Session in the DAO Constructor, and have transaction demarcation code at the business layer (heck, even create some Dynamic Proxies if needed). At least it is easier to see where a transaction must start and where it must end). So what I'm saying is that even if your code can get the OP around with his problem in one hour as opposed to several hours / days I would still recommend Olaf approach. Off topic: 1+ for hibernate "try-with-resources" support :D.